# URL management using Yii

Tags: yii, yii-url-manager

I have url: /profile/profileBase/index where "profile" is module, "profileBase" is controller and "index" is action.
I want to url manager would accept route like: /profile/read/index
where "read" could be alias of controller.
Is there any way to do this using url manager rules?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => array(
          'profile/read/index '=>'profile/profileBase/index'
        ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simply add the following rule in `urlManager` config :

```
'profile/read/index'=>'profile/profileBase/index',
```